# как в jquery прописать this чтобы при foreach отработала функция для каждого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
                    <script>
function updateCounter2() {
            setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/counter/",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                ## думаю здесь ошибка - для одног элемента отраабтывает (нужно this видимо ввести) 
                    document.getElementById('sidemenu2').innerHTML = '';
                    $("#sidemenu2").text(data.basket_count);
                }
            });
            }, 2000);
        };

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.addbasket.float-rigth')).forEach(updItem => {
            updItem.addEventListener("click", () => updateCounter2(updItem.innerText));
})
                    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container results-container list-p">
        
        <div class="page-header titlecat h4">
            
            <small class="text-title">ЗАПЧАСТИ ДЛЯ ТО&nbsp;
                <i class="bi bi-chevron-right">
                </i>&nbsp;
            </small>
            
            
            <a href="/catalog/406/">Фильтры масляные
            </a>
            
        </div>
        
    <div class="page collapse show">

        <div class="row align-items-center list-p backg">
             <div class="col-sm-3 kod col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-2 text-right text-muted" title="135147">
               <div class="row prod7">
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-12"><img src="/media/product-img/pusto-mini.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/media/product-img/pusto-mini.jpg';"></div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-10">
                135147
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-10">
                <div class="cardprod">
                    
                   <a class="product-name" id="load-product" title="подробнее..." href="/catalog/406/135147/" data-id="135147">
                        Фильтр масляный Logan, Sandero, Largus, Duster, Megane I-II, Clio I-III, Kangoo, Laguna, Almera (G11/15) 12--
                            <div class="tumb" style="display: none;">
                                <img id="135147" src="/media/product-img/pusto.jpg">
                            </div>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="productload" class="modal fade show" style="z-index: 99999999999;">
                </div>
                <div class="float-left small brt">
                
                    <span title="артикул товара: TC1001" class="mr-2">
                        <i class="text-muted ert ">артикул:
                        </i>TC1001
                    </span>
                    
                    
                    <span title="в упаковке: 48  шт" class="mr-3"><i class="text-muted ert">в упак: </i>48 шт
                    </span>
                    
                    
                
                
                
                
                            
                    
                
                
                </div>
                <div class="manufactur small  mr-2">
                    
                    TOTACHI 
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-12 text-right addcartpost2">
                <form class="addcartpost addcarts" action="." method="POST">
                
                    <span class="text-muted small rt mr-1">
                        
                        
                        50 шт
                        
                        
                    </span>
                
                        
                    
                    <div class="amount">
                            221,35
                    </div>

                
                

<i class="i bi-file-minus" title="уменьшение">
</i>
<input class="id_pr" type="hidden" name="id_pr" value="135147" required="" id="id_pr">
<input title="миним. норма отпуска 1 шт" class="product id_quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" required="" id="id_quantity" max="50">
<input class="artikul" type="hidden" name="artikul" value="TC1001" id="artikul">
<input class="brend" type="hidden" name="brend" value="TOTACHI" id="brend">
<input class="name" type="hidden" name="name" value="Фильтр масляный Logan, Sandero, Largus, Duster, Megane I-II, Clio I-III, Kangoo, Laguna, Almera (G11/15) 12--" id="name">
<input class="upakovka_f" type="hidden" name="upakovka_f" value="48" id="upakovka_f">
<input class="shtuk_e" type="hidden" name="shtuk_e" value="шт" id="shtuk_e">
<input class="min_kol" type="hidden" name="min_kol" value="1" id="min_kol">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="False" id="id_update">
<i class="bi bi-file-plus" title="увеличение">
</i>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
<div class="addbasket float-rigth">
    <input id="add-toast" class="update" type="submit" value="купить">
    <span id="sidemenu2" class="s2-y" style="background-color: rgb(185 140 40);"></span>

</div>

                </form>
            </div>


            

        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="container results-container list-p">
        
    <div class="page collapse show">

        <div class="row align-items-center list-p backg">
             <div class="col-sm-3 kod col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-2 text-right text-muted" title="167958">
               <div class="row prod7">
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-12"><img src="/media/product-img/pusto-mini.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/media/product-img/pusto-mini.jpg';"></div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-10">
                167958
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-10">
                <div class="cardprod">
                    
                   <a class="product-name" id="load-product" title="подробнее..." href="/catalog/406/167958/" data-id="167958">
                        Фильтр масляный Logan, Sandero, Largus, Duster, Megane I-II, Clio I-III, Kangoo, Laguna, Almera (G11/15) 12-- (24)
                            <div class="tumb" style="display: none;">
                                <img id="167958" src="/media/product-img/pusto.jpg">
                            </div>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="productload" class="modal fade show" style="z-index: 99999999999;">
                </div>
                <div class="float-left small brt">
                
                    <span title="артикул товара: NF1018" class="mr-2">
                        <i class="text-muted ert ">артикул:
                        </i>NF1018
                    </span>
                    
                    
                    <span title="в упаковке: 20  шт" class="mr-3"><i class="text-muted ert">в упак: </i>20 шт
                    </span>
                    
                    
                
                
                
                
                            
                    
                
                
                </div>
                <div class="manufactur small  mr-2">
                    
                    Невский фильтр 
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-12 text-right addcartpost2">
                <form class="addcartpost addcarts" action="." method="POST">
                
                    <span class="text-muted small rt mr-1">
                        
                        
                        11 шт
                        
                        
                    </span>
                
                        
                    
                    <div class="amount">
                            196,00
                    </div>

                
                

<i class="i bi-file-minus" title="уменьшение">
</i>
<input class="id_pr" type="hidden" name="id_pr" value="167958" required="" id="id_pr">
<input title="миним. норма отпуска 1 шт" class="product id_quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" required="" id="id_quantity" max="11">
<input class="artikul" type="hidden" name="artikul" value="NF1018" id="artikul">
<input class="brend" type="hidden" name="brend" value="Невский фильтр" id="brend">
<input class="name" type="hidden" name="name" value="Фильтр масляный Logan, Sandero, Largus, Duster, Megane I-II, Clio I-III, Kangoo, Laguna, Almera (G11/15) 12-- (24)" id="name">
<input class="upakovka_f" type="hidden" name="upakovka_f" value="20" id="upakovka_f">
<input class="shtuk_e" type="hidden" name="shtuk_e" value="шт" id="shtuk_e">
<input class="min_kol" type="hidden" name="min_kol" value="1" id="min_kol">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="False" id="id_update">
<i class="bi bi-file-plus" title="увеличение">
</i>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
<div class="addbasket float-rigth">
    <input id="add-toast" class="update" type="submit" value="купить">
    <span id="sidemenu2" class="s2-y" style="background-color: rgb(185 140 40);"></span>

</div>

                </form>
            </div>


            

        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Как правильно вписать  это в функцию для foreach   document.getElementById('sidemenu2').innerHTML = '';
                    $(this).text(data.basket_count);

Comment: Причем тут this и как вы хотите его использовать? При чем тут forEach?

Comment: $('#sidemenu2') я понел чтj this пишется так для каждого элемента

Comment: Для работы с `this` а `addEventListener` - нужно использовать `function(){}`, не стрелочной функцией...

Comment: можете показать на данном примере пожалуйста

Comment: Еще раз - зачем вам this? Вы понимаете, что это такое? Если даже в событии клика вы получите какой то this, то в фукнции updateCounter2 в методе success ajax запроса он уже будет совершенно другой

Comment: все понел! А как тогда сделать чтобы в цикле  $("#sidemenu2").text(data.basket_count); выводил для каждого элемента при запросе функции

Comment: У вас в примере только один цикл, который создает слушателя события клика... все...

Comment: я итак понимаю что цикл у меня один раз работае т для первого элемента и все а для второго почему то ответ выводит в первом  элементе

Comment: id элемента на всей странице должен быть уникальным, а у вас повторяется. После выполнения аякс запроса берется первый попавшийся элемент и ему присваиваются значения. При этом, при вызове фукнции, передаете аргументы, хотя функция, никакие аргументы не ожидает. Возможно стоит передавать id элемента, в который надо записать данные.